# Count posts for each year

Tags: archives, count

I'm using the following code to list all years from my blog, I guess we can call it an archive.

```
<?php
$years = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(post_date) FROM $wpdb->posts ORDER BY post_date DESC");
foreach($years as $year) : ?>
    <?php echo $year ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

What I'd like to achieve though is to also display, in front of each year, the number of posts (count) that each year has. Example:

```
2015 (5 posts)
2014 (3 posts)
2011 (10 posts)
```

I found a hint somewhere and tried to implement it, but didn't work. Here's what I was trying:

```
<?php
$years = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(post_date) FROM $wpdb->posts ORDER BY post_date DESC");
$count = $years->post_count;
foreach($years as $year) : ?>
    <?php echo $year ?> (<?php echo $count ?> posts)
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Any ideas?

Thank you.

**EDIT @David**

```
<?php 
/** Grab the years that contain published posts, and a count of how many */
$query = $wpdb->prepare('
            SELECT YEAR(%1$s.post_date) AS `year`, count(%1$s.ID) as `posts`
            FROM %1$s
            WHERE %1$s.post_type IN ("post")
            AND %1$s.post_status IN ("publish")
            GROUP BY YEAR(%1$s.post_date)
            ORDER BY %1$s.post_date DESC',
            $wpdb->posts
        );
$results = $wpdb->get_results($query);

/** Create the '$years' array, a list of all yearly archives */
$years = array();
if(!empty($results)) : foreach($results as $result) :

        $url = get_year_link($result->year);                            // The archive link URL for the current year
        $text = $result->year;                                          // The archive link text for the current year
        $count = $result->posts;                                        // The number of posts in the current year
        $years[] = get_archives_link($url, $text, 'html', '', $count);  // Create the archive link for the current year

    endforeach;
endif;
?>
<a href="<?php echo $url; ?>"><li><?php echo $text ?> <span class="lower">(<?php echo $count ?>)</span></li></a>
```

Comment: I'll post an answer later if no one else does, but you are on the right track. Your issue is that you are trying to count the posts from the `$years` query, which wont work.

Answer (score 3):

## The Easy Way

This is by far and away the easiest approach to this, but unless you are willing to be a little bit flexible with how you present your archive it's not for you.

The easy solution is achieved using the [`wp_get_archives()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_archives) function. Unfortunately though there is no filter available to manipulate the output, so you'll be left with a list like this. The count will not be part of the link -

> 2015 (5)
>   2014 (3)
>   2011 (10)

And here is the code -

```
$args = array(
    'type'              => 'yearly',
    'show_post_count'   => true
);
wp_get_archives($args);
```

## The Hard Way

So if you decide the easy way isn't for you that only leave the hard way. Essentially we are replicating the functionality of `wp_get_archives()`, but you can format the output exactly as you wish.

The code below makes use of a custom query, not dissimilar from your own (except that we grab the count of posts as well as the years), as well as the functions [`get_year_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_year_link) and [`get_archives_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_archives_link).

The output will leave you with a list formatted as you posted in the update to your question. The count will be part of the link -

> 2015 (5)
>   2014 (3)
>   2011 (10)

And here is the code -

```
/** Grab the years that contain published posts, and a count of how many */
$query = $wpdb->prepare('
            SELECT YEAR(%1$s.post_date) AS `year`, count(%1$s.ID) as `posts`
            FROM %1$s
            WHERE %1$s.post_type IN ("post")
            AND %1$s.post_status IN ("publish")
            GROUP BY YEAR(%1$s.post_date)
            ORDER BY %1$s.post_date',
            $wpdb->posts
        );
$results = $wpdb->get_results($query);      

/** Create the '$years' array, a list of all yearly archives */
$years = array();
if(!empty($results)) : foreach($results as $result) :

        $count = '<span class="lower">(' . $result->posts . ')</span>';      // The number of posts in the current year
        $url = get_year_link($result->year);                                    // The archive link URL for the current year
        $text = '<li>' . $result->year . ' ' . $count . '</li>';                // The archive link text for the current year
        $years[] = get_archives_link($url, $text, 'html');                      // Create the archive link for the current year

    endforeach;
endif;

/** Output the custom archive list */
echo join("\n", $years);
```

## Edit

Based on your comment, I've amended my answer above slightly.

The reason that you were only able to output one year is because you were only explicity echoing the last year after the `foreach` loop.  What the code does is add each year to the `$years` array, and then outputs all of them using the final line - echo join("\n", $years);

Comment: Thank you! :) I tried changing it a little bit but for some reason it's showing me only one year! Basically I'm not using the echo but instead creating the tag after the code. See my edit please.

Comment: Please see my update, hopefully this helps.

Comment: It's giving me blank li's between li's with years and the url is wrong (it's outputting /date/2011 for example) but I have a custom permalink for dates :\ that's why I was creating a custom output with php tags. Is there a way I can do it like this? Also, I need to wrap the li's with `<a>` that is why using get_archives_link won't work.

Comment: Try now, I'd added an extra `</li>` by mistake. And fine, change the output as required.  The important thing to remeber is that, as you loop, `$result->year` is the year and `$result->count` is the number of posts.

Comment: The problem is that get_archives_link will always output an `<a>` to the second parameter, which is the year :x

Comment: Then don't use that function :) build the link yourself using the second part of my answer.

Comment: How can I make it output all years and not only just one like you said?

Comment: It does output all of the year's...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21387/discussion-between-coldpumpkin-and-david-gard).

Answer (score 2):

Just had simmilar problem and because I don't feel comfortable with performing DB queries in rendered php sites, I made this function, witch uses wp_get_archives() and regex. It returns array with year as the key and number of posts as the value.

## The middle way:

```
function load_years() {
  $args = array(
    'type'              => 'yearly',
    'show_post_count'   => true
  );
  ob_start();
  wp_get_archives($args);
  $item = ob_get_contents(); 
  ob_end_clean(); 
  $pattern = '/\'>(\d\d\d\d)<.*nbsp;\((\d*)/';
  preg_match_all($pattern, $item, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
  $years_array = array();
  foreach ($matches[1] as $key => $value) {
      $year = $matches[1][$key][0];
      $posts = $matches[2][$key][0];
      $years_array[$year] = $posts;
  }
  return $years_array;
}
```