# How do I add a count to each month in this archive code?

Tags: archives

I use the code below for a page listing months/posts.

I want to add a post-count to each month, but have no idea how to do it.

I'm also wondering if there's a better way to do what the code does.

```
// Declare some helper vars
$previous_year = $year = 0;
$previous_month = $month = 0;
$dl_open = false;

// Get the posts
$myposts = get_posts('numberposts=-1&orderby=post_date&order=DESC');
?>

<?php foreach($myposts as $post) : ?>

<?php
// Setup the post variables
setup_postdata($post);
$year = mysql2date('Y', $post->post_date);
$month = mysql2date('n', $post->post_date);
$day = mysql2date('d', $post->post_date);
?>

<?php if($year != $previous_year || $month != $previous_month) : ?>

<?php if($dl_open == true) : ?>
</dl>
<?php endif; ?>

<h3><?php the_time('F Y'); ?></h3>

<dl id="post-list">

<?php $dl_open = true; ?>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php $previous_year = $year; $previous_month = $month; ?>

<dt><?php the_time('d'); ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Read this Note."><?php the_title(); ?></a></dt>
<dd><?php //the_excerpt(); ?></dd>

<?php endforeach; ?>

</dl>
```

Comment: This should be helpful: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/178816/count-posts-for-each-year

Comment: @ Dave Romsey ... thanks. Sorry for my slow reply - unexpected surgery. Your link looks useful - I'll study when able. :-)

Comment: I hope you have a speedy recovery and that the link helps too! :-)